# Can I disable shifting in specific BottomNavigationView item on specific logic?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

Currently I have an implementation like this-

```
    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                ......
     switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.actionUser:
          if(userLoggedIn) {
              mHomePresenter.btnUser();
          }
          else {
              showLongToast("User Not Logged In");
          }
          break;
    });
```

The logical **else** part where I will show the **toast message**, neither I want the BottomNavigationView to shift nor the change of menu icon colour.

How I can implement such logic only on this specific part? All the other menu item will persist the default shifting logic.

Comment: Hi Fatima
Can you please provide more information. It's not clear. It would be great if you can provide some running example.

Comment: I've already got a solution. See below the accepted answer. Thanks for your concern! @ShravanJain

Comment: Awesome Yrr .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is quite simple, for the condition you want the transition to happen, return `true` for the condition where you dont want return `false`

Taking your code into account, it should be

```
mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionUser:
            if(userLoggedIn) {
                mHomePresenter.btnUser();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                showLongToast("User Not Logged In");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

if you check the documentation for the Navigation selection listener, you can see

```
/**
 * Listener for handling selection events on bottom navigation items.
 */
public interface OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    /**
     * Called when an item in the bottom navigation menu is selected.
     *
     * @param item The selected item
     *
     * @return true to display the item as the selected item and false if the item should not
     *         be selected. Consider setting non-selectable items as disabled preemptively to
     *         make them appear non-interactive.
     */
    boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!! It worked! I'm a beginner. That shifting helper class was boiling up my head! 

Thanks for pointing out this easiest solution!